# Mac iTerm commands permission denied

Tags: git, ssh, terminal, permission-denied

Today I started up my `iTerm` and I'm getting permission denied for most of my commands in `terminal`.

For example if I run `pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` I get the output `permission denied: /Users/coreyvincent/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

I'm also getting `permission denied (public key)` when I try to ssh into my web app, which was the first instance where I found that my commands were not working.

Not sure what caused this or how to fix it. I've tried re-adding my public keys(ssh-keygen), and I've tried a couple `chmod` commands, but I don't really know what I'm doing there.

```
ls -l
total 301
drwxrwxr-x+ 157 root          admin   5338 Feb  8 17:30 Applications
drwxrwxr-x    6 root          admin    204 Apr 17  2015 Developer
drwxrwxr-x   10 root          admin    340 Oct 22  2014 Incompatible Software
drwxr-xr-x+  77 root          wheel   2618 Nov  8  2016 Library
drwxr-xr-x    3 coreyvincent  wheel    102 Sep  8  2016 Log
drwxr-xr-x@   2 root          wheel     68 Sep  9  2014 Network
-rw-r--r--@   1 coreyvincent  admin      1 Oct 24  2008 Shockwave Log
drwxr-xr-x+   4 root          wheel    136 Oct 21  2014 System
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root          wheel     49 Jun 19  2012 User Information ->         /Library/Documentation/User Information.localized
drwxr-xr-x    7 root          admin    238 Nov 18  2016 Users
-rw-r--r--    1 coreyvincent  admin    396 Sep 23  2008 Users:coreyvincent:Library:Application Support:Adobe:Dreamweaver 9:Configurationssh_hosts
drwxrwxrwt@   3 root          admin    102 Feb  9 07:27 Volumes
drwxr-xr-x@  39 root          wheel   1326 Aug 24  2015 bin
drwxrwxr-t@   2 root          admin     68 Sep  9  2014 cores
dr-xr-xr-x    3 root          wheel   4538 Feb  8 17:24 dev
-rw-r--r--    1 coreyvincent  wheel  59919 Jul  8  2016 dex_Log.html
-rw-r--r--    1 coreyvincent  wheel  39883 Jul  8  2016 dex_Log.txt
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root          wheel     11 Oct 21  2014 etc -> private/etc
dr-xr-xr-x    2 root          wheel      1 Feb  9 09:48 home
-rw-r--r--@   1 root          wheel    313 Oct  1  2014 installer.failurerequests
-rw-r--r--    1 coreyvincent  wheel   4676 Apr 29  2015 launcher.log
-rw-r--r--    1 coreyvincent  wheel    141 Jul 12  2017 log.out
dr-xr-xr-x    2 root          wheel      1 Feb  9 09:48 net
drwxr-xr-x@   5 root          wheel    170 Nov 21 07:41 opt
drwx------   24 coreyvincent  wheel    816 Jan 18  2016 pgsql
drwxr-xr-x@   6 root          wheel    204 Oct 21  2014 private
drwxr-xr-x@  59 root          wheel   2006 Aug  2  2017 sbin
-rw-rw-rw-    1 coreyvincent  wheel   1309 Feb  5 19:22 sockets.log
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root          wheel     11 Oct 21  2014 tmp -> private/tmp
drwxr-xr-x    3 coreyvincent  wheel    102 Jan 11  2016 user
drwxr-xr-x@  13 root          wheel    442 Apr 17  2015 usr
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root          wheel     11 Oct 21  2014 var -> private/var

 ls -l ~/.ssh
ls: .config.swp: Permission denied
ls: authorized_keys: Permission denied
ls: config: Permission denied
ls: id_dsa: Permission denied
ls: id_dsa.pub: Permission denied
ls: id_rsa: Permission denied
ls: id_rsa.pub: Permission denied
ls: known_hosts: Permission denied
ls: known_hosts.old: Permission denied
 sudo ls -l ~/.ssh
Password:
total 72
-rw-------  1 coreyvincent  staff  12288 Nov  5  2015 .config.swp
-rw-r--r--  1 root          staff      0 Feb  9 09:40 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 coreyvincent  staff     52 Nov  5  2015 config
-rw-------  1 coreyvincent  staff    668 Feb 10  2016 id_dsa
-rw-r--r--  1 coreyvincent  staff    629 Feb 10  2016 id_dsa.pub
-rw-------  1 coreyvincent  staff   3247 Jan 23 15:37 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 coreyvincent  staff    748 Jan 23 15:37 id_rsa.pub
-rw-------  1 coreyvincent  staff   1222 Nov 22 15:46 known_hosts
-rw-r--r--  1 coreyvincent  staff      0 Nov 22 11:45 known_hosts.old  

ls -ld ~/.ssh
drw-r--r--  11 coreyvincent  staff  374 Feb  9 09:40 /Users/coreyvincent/.ssh
```

Any help would be much appreciated. At this point I can't seem to access anything or connect to Github...

Comment: Check your user with `who am i` and use `ls -l` to view the read/write/execute permissions on your files (and ensure that they do in fact belong to you, the current user). Finally, read the man page on chmod and try to add any details you can about the specific files/any commands you remember executing before that could have affected your machine. Frankly it’s difficult for us to diagnose your specific problem without more information

Comment: I edited the post with my `ls -l` permissions. Is there any more info I can give to help solve this? @DavidBenKnoble

Comment: So that looks like the permissions of the files/dirs in the root directory `/`—what about specific files youve tried to access? That ssh directory for example—id bet after thinking it’s got the wrong permissions so any thing using ssh wont work

Comment: Looking back I did run `chmod 700 ~/.ssh` and `chmod 644 ~/.ssh` when I found a post that was supposed to fix this issue. I think it got worse after that. @DavidBenKnoble

Comment: Hmm. I cant remember the exact recommended ssh directory permissions offhand, but my laptop (man ssh) is telling me it should be 700. For details on the files within, check the man page.

Comment: Could you provide the `ls -l ~/.ssh` output? It also needs to belong to you, which requires chown to fix

Comment: I've edited the post with the `ls -l ~/.ssh` output. Which I can only get to show when I use `sudo`. What is the man page you speak of? @DavidBenKnoble

Comment: Man ssh. One more thing, sorry—i really meant `ls -ld ~/.ssh`; that is, the permissions on the directory itself. You clearly dont have them, or you wouldnt need sudo.

Comment: When you update with that ill put up an answer with chown

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164852/discussion-between-corey-and-david-ben-knoble).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

```
$ ls -ld ~/.ssh
drw-r--r--  11 coreyvincent  staff  374 Feb  9 09:40 /Users/coreyvincent/.ssh
```

Notice the permissions: `drw-r--r--`: it's a directory (`d`), it's read-write by the owner (`rw-`) and readable by everyone else (`r--r--`). However, in order to enter a directory, you need executable permissions. With read/write access, you can view information about the directory, but that's about it.

## Solution

Add executable permission back. I avoid using the octal notation when I can because it's difficult for me to quickly parse; the symbolic representation (`rwx`) by contrast is immediately evident. So,

> `$ chmod u+x ~/.ssh`

is the equivalent of adding executable permission for the user only.

#### Other Information

`man ssh` recommends the following for the `~/.ssh` directory:

> This directory is the default location for all user-specific configuration and authentication information. There is no general requirement to keep the entire contents of this directory secret, but the recommended permissions are read/write/execute for the user, and not accessible by others.

To follow that recommendation, I'd recommend

```
$ chmod go-r ~/.ssh
```

since you currently have group (`g`) and other (`o`) permissions set to read only (`r--`).

Further, `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is recommended to be `rw-------`. Simply use the same steps above with that file. As for the rest of the files, they accurately reflect the guidelines (or, in the case of `~/.ssh/config`, the requirements) in `man ssh`.

#### Further reading

- `man ssh`
- `man chmod`